# How can I pass a module's function as a reference to another module in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, reference, function-pointers, perl-module

How can I pass a reference to a module's function as parameter in a function call of another module?
I tried the following (simple example):
This is the module that has a function (process_staff) that takes as a parameter a function reference (is_ok).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

package Objs::Processing;  

sub new {  
    my ($class) = @_;  
    bless {} ;      
}  

sub process_staff {  
    my ($employee, $func) = @_;  
    if($func->is_ok($employee)) {  
        print "Is ok to process\n";  
    }  
    else {  
        print "Not ok to process\n";  
    }  
}  
1;
```

This is the module that implements the passed function (is_ok)

```
#!usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

package Objs::Employee;  

my $started;  

sub new {  
    my ($class) = @_;  
    my $cur_time = localtime;  
    my $self = {  
        started => $cur_time,  
    };  
    print "Time: $cur_time \n";  
    bless $self;  
}  

sub get_started {  
    my ($class) = @_;  
    return $class->{started};  
}  

sub set_started {  
    my ($class, $value) = @_;  
    $class->{started} = $value;  
}  

sub is_ok {  
    my ($emp) = @_;  
    print "In is ok I received:\n";  
    use Data::Dumper;   
    print Dumper($emp);  
    return 1;  
}
```

This is my test script that I run:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

use Objs::Manager;  
use Objs::Processing;  

my $emp = Objs::Manager->new('John Smith');    
use Data::Dumper;    
print Dumper($emp);  

my $processor = Objs::Processing->new();   
$processor->process_staff(\&$emp->is_ok);   #error is here
```

I get a:

```
Not a CODE reference at testScript.pl line 14.
```

I also tried:  `$processor->process_staff(\&$emp->is_ok());` but also still does not work.
What am I doing wrong here

Comment: show a complete example; where's is_ok defined?

Comment: @ysth:Updated OP.I made a mistake in copy/paste and did not include it.Now it is there

Comment: sidenote; `$emp->is_ok()` is same thing as `$emp->is_ok`

Answer (score 4):

You appear to want to pass an object and a method to call on it; the easiest way to do that would be:

```
$processor->process_staff( sub { $emp->is_ok } );
```

where process_staff looks like:

```
sub process_staff {
    my ($self, $func) = @_;
    if ( $func->() ) {
        ...
```

or you can pass the reference and the object separately:

```
sub process_staff {
    my ($self, $emp, $method) = @_;
    if ( $emp->$method() ) {
    ...

$processor->process_staff( $emp, $emp->can('is_ok') );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work with:

```
$processor->process_staff(\&Objs::Employee::is_ok);
```

where you pass in the method ref.

and where you currently have

```
if( $func->is_ok($employee) ) {
```

you need

```
if( $func->( $employee ) ) {
```

This is because you cannot reference named methods simply from an object, by the syntax `\&$obj->method`.

However, in your example code it is not at all clear why you don't do this instead:

```
if( $employee->is_ok() ) {
```

in which case you would not need to reference the method to call in `process_staff` at all. There are also other ways to achieve the same method indirection that might give you better encapsulation in future.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.It is like I should treat the function as a class function for this to work. Can't I pass an instance function?

Comment: @Cratylus: Instances don't have functions as such (I prefer to say "method", to differentiate from non-OO Perl). In Perl, the package holds functions, and it is how you process the params that decides whether or not the function becomes a class method or instance method in practice. That makes it impossible for core syntax in Perl to differentiate between "instance" and "class" methods, although it  is possible to build an OO system in Perl that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression:

```
$processor->process_staff(\&$emp->is_ok);
```

You are saying "call the method `$emp->is_ok`, take the return value, treat it as a `CODE` reference, dereference it, and return a reference to that. That doesn't work, since the return value from that sub is not a `CODE` reference.

To do what you want, you can use a reference to an anonymous sub to wrap the call to your object method:

```
$processor->process_staff( sub { $emp->is_ok } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass anonymous coderef which returns result from desired method,

```
$processor->process_staff(sub{ $emp->is_ok(@_) });
```

`@_` can be dropped as `is_ok` method doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's not specifically what you asked for, but I think you simply need the following:

```
sub process_staff {  
    my ($self, $emp) = @_;  
    if ($emp->is_ok()) {  
        print "Is ok to process\n";  
    }  
    else {  
        print "Not ok to process\n";  
    }  
}  

$processor->process_staff($emp);
```